# Converting Subquery to a join

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I'm learning about joins in SQL and I am trying to create a subquery and convert it into a join so it does the same thing.

The subqueries I'm using is:

```
SELECT CustomerID
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
where SalesOrderID IN (SELECT SalesOrderID
                       FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
                       WHERE ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID
                                           FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail
                                           WHERE OrderQty >2));
```

So I essentially want to get the product ID's for order with a quantity over 2 from one table, feed this list into another table to get the salesorderID'S and then finally retrieve the customer id's.

I know I can do the same thing by creating a join, I had a go at this below:

```
SELECT CustomerID
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS soh, Sales.SalesOrderDetail as sod, Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail AS pod
WHERE soh.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
AND sod.ProductID = pod.ProductID
AND pod.OrderQty >2;
```

I think this should retrieve the same data however when I run it I get more results from the join. I'm not understanding how these 2 queries are different from each other. Can anyone help?
Thank you!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results to clarify your question.

Comment: Hello Dale, I'm using the AdventureWorks2012

 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/samples/adventureworks-install-configure?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=ssms) 

data to play around with. 
The first query returns 23773 rows fairly quickly whereas the join returns 1139318 rows and takes 30 seconds to execute.

Comment: First learn how to use explicit joins rather than the very out of fashion comma joins.

Comment: Thanks, yep I've figured that out too now:

```SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS soh
INNER JOIN  Sales.SalesOrderDetail as sod
ON soh.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
INNER JOIN Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail AS pod
ON sod.ProductID = pod.ProductID
AND pod.OrderQty >2;```

Answer (score 1):

The `IN` condition in your first query means that only one matching row is returned for each parameter. Taking for example,

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE Id IN (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2)
```

(Assuming SomeTable exists with an unique Id column and rows containing 1 and 2) would return only two results.

When you JOIN instead, you're combining the result sets from your query so you end up with the same data, but with some rows duplicated because (for example) a SalesOrderID value appears multiple times in the SalesOrderDetail table.

You can get around this by using a DISTINCT command in your query, that means you'll only get unique results, but for this case -- the subquery approach with `IN` probably represents your needs better.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand now, it was due to duplicates. I added DISTINCT to all the select clauses and they returned matching data for both.